# C++ omitting or adding extra character

Tags: c++, string

So I have a funny error. I have this piece of code (this is a partial code):

```
 if (isQuote(ch))
                {
                    //Add it to the Buffer
                    strBuffer += ch;

                    do
                    {
                        //get Next Character from ifstream and add it to the strBuffer
                        getNextAndAdd(ch);


                        // check whether it is a \\'
                        if (isBackslash(ch) && (this -> peek() == '"'))
                        {
                            //if it is a backslash, activate check checkQuote
                            checkQuote = true;
                        }
                        //if it is another quote, dectivate check Quote otherwise, break the system
                        if (isQuote(ch))
                        {
                             if (checkQuote)
                             {
                                 checkQuote = false;
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 break;
                             }
                        }
                        //IF EOF, do NOT continue repeating the last character
                        if (input -> eof()){break;}

                    }
                    while (isPrintable(ch)); // check that it falls within the SXL acceptance range
                    if (ch == '"')
                    {
                        //IF EOF, do NOT continue repeating the last character
                        if (input -> eof()){break;}

                        //output Buffer for TEST purposes
                        cout << strBuffer << endl;

                        //create new token and push it into the vector
                        tk = new Token (tkstring, strBuffer, row, col);
                        tokensUsed.push_back(tk);
                        startNewString();
                    }
                    tokenMatch = true;
                }
```

getNextAndAdd(ch) translate to

```
void getNextAndAdd(char ch)
    {
       ch = nextChar();
       strBuffer += ch;
    }
```

and I am giving it some test data. I have a text file in which i input the test Data. The problem lies that if I write for example `"abc" "def"` with just ONE Space between them it will read it as `"abc" 123` which the latter is a NUMBER, totally different IF I do TWO Space meaning `"abc"  "def"`
then it WILL read it as 2 strings. I also checked if it is a WHITESPACE, but the latter case with 2 SPACES has recognised that last empty space is actually a whitespace

any idea why? I tried removing the last letter of the string saying maybe it was that fault but it ended up with `"hello`

Thanks

Comment: The reason `gdb` exists. You're talking about a finite series of actions taken with a specific test case. Debugging into this is *ideal*, since you already know *that* it breaks, *and* have solid locations where to look (the posted code we can't run). **Step through your breakages with a debugger**.

Comment: I do not know why, but Code::Blocks is NOT letting me debug even though I followed every instruction found.. it just pops a black screen for a millisecond and closes

Answer (score 1):

```
void getNextAndAdd(char ch)
{
   ch = nextChar();
   strBuffer += ch;
}
```

You might think this would return the character you just read in `ch`. You would be wrong.

As a result, after executing this code:

```
if (isQuote(ch))
{
    //Add it to the Buffer
    strBuffer += ch;

    do
    {
        //get Next Character from ifstream and add it to the strBuffer
        getNextAndAdd(ch);
```

`ch` *will* contain a quote, and two quotes will have been appended to `strBuffer`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have a ch = nextChar(); in the beginning, as this make part of another while loop

Comment: Before the `if (isQuote(ch))` part, right? My point still stands.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing 2 lines of code.

the first change was under `isQuote` where I deleted that `strBuffer += ch` and instead added a `addAndGetNext(ch)` under the do{} loop

Another `addAndGetNext(ch)` was added under the last loop statement.